AlpineJS model not updating via jQuery ajax callback
I am trying to update a checkbox value tied to a AlipneJS data model based on the response of a jquery ajax call.
However it doesn't seem to work when I try to update the data model for the checkbox in the jQuery callback method. It updates fine before the jquery call (the commented out line works fine).
What am I missing? Thanks for your help in advance.
<html>
<head>
    <!--- jQuery --->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--- Bootstrap --->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--- Include Alpinejs --->
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.14.1/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width:50%;margin:auto;line-height:2em;">
        <div x-data="startup">
            <form>
                <div>Checkbox<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input big-checkbox material" type="checkbox" value="" id="yes" x-model="val_yes">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                    Yes
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" @click.prevent="callAPI()">Call API</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
         document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
            Alpine.data('startup', () => ({
                val_yes: false,
                callAPI()
                    {
                        //this.val_yes = true;
                        $.ajax({
                                url:"https://zenquotes.io/api/today",
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success: function(json) 
                                    {
                                        this.val_yes = true;
                                    }
                            });
                    
                    }
            }))
        })
    </script>

</body>
</html>



Does this answer your question? How to access the correct `this` inside a callback

TL;DR use success: (json) => { this.val_yes = true; }

Thank you. Using the arrow function works

The problem is that this inside your success callback is not the same as this before you make $.ajax call, therefore when you try updating the data, it's not working as expected.
This is one way to fix the issue using bind from JavaScript, but you could also use jQuery.proxy from jQuery.
<html>
<head>
    <!--- jQuery --->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--- Bootstrap --->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--- Include Alpinejs --->
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.14.1/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width:50%;margin:auto;line-height:2em;">
        <div x-data="startup">
            <form>
                <div>Checkbox<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input big-checkbox material" type="checkbox" value="" id="yes" x-model="val_yes">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                    Yes
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" @click.prevent="callAPI()">Call API</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
         document.addEventListener(
            'alpine:init', 
            () => {
                Alpine.data(
                    'startup', 
                    () => ({
                        val_yes: false,
                        callAPI() {
                            // this.val_yes = true;
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "https://zenquotes.io/api/today",
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success: function(json) {
                                    this.val_yes = true;
                                }.bind(this)
                            });
                        }
                    })
                )
            }
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>

